# Laravel project creation, Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to create a project using a composer. I use the following command. My folder consist of another project but in a separate folder.

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog
```

[image]

The error I get is,

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
```

[image]

[image]

Some answers in [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) says to upgrade the PHP. But in my case it's already updated to newest version. `php -v` says,

[image]

Is there any solution? Any suggestion is warmly welcome.

Edit: I installed the `php mbstring` but I get the same error.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried installing the mbstring extension for PHP?

Comment: its right there, you are missing extensions that it requires.

Comment: It's strange, I created new laraval project one week ago. No errors. Let me install that.

Comment: Please share all error messages in text form. Also, share your attempts to resolve them

Answer (score 0):

If you're running PHP 5

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mbstring
```

If you're running PHP 7

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mbstring
```

Also, read Laravel's requirements: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/installation

There may be other dependencies you haven't installed:

- PHP >= 5.6.4
- OpenSSL PHP Extension
- PDO PHP Extension
- Mbstring PHP Extension
- Tokenizer PHP Extension
- XML PHP Extension